# JavaScript Scope or AngularJS Promise $q in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb

I have problem with the Scope of JS functions and/or Angularjs promise and $q. I looked up some examples but I did not get it at all.

In my app I have some data saved in indexeddb of my browser. In Frontend there is an input field with autocomplete function. The value of the input field goes to my angularjs Controller and calls a function. The function should return the found values. The logic of finding values from indexeddb is working fine.

The problem is that I return my array before the values are pushed into the array. So I am not sure if I need to change some stuff in JavaScript scope or to use Angularjs stuff.

Here is my Controller:

```
 var AutocompleteController = function($scope, $http, $q) {

 $scope.getCodeFromDB = function(val) {
        var codes = [];
            var openDbRequest = indexedDB.open('testDb', 1);

            openDbRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
                var db = e.target.result;
                var transaction = db.transaction("codeobjekt");

                transaction.objectStore("codeobjekt")
                    .openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound(val, val + '\uffff'))
                    .onsuccess = function (e) {
                    var cursor = e.target.result;
                    if (cursor) {
                        codes.push(cursor.value.code); //gets filled
                        console.log(cursor.value.code);
                        cursor.continue();
                    }
                };
            };

        console.log(codes); //is empty
        return codes;
    };
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your code you try to use an array filled after the return.

Try using the $q service provides by angular like that.

```
var AutocompleteController = function($scope, $http, $q) {

    $scope.getCodeFromDB = function(val) {
        var def= $q.defer(),
            codes = [],
        openDbRequest = indexedDB.open('testDb', 1);

        openDbRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
        var db = e.target.result;
            var transaction = db.transaction("codeobjekt");

            transaction.objectStore("codeobjekt")
                .openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound(val, val + '\uffff'))
                .onsuccess = function (e) {
                var cursor = e.target.result;
                if (cursor) {
                    codes.push(cursor.value.code); //gets filled
                    console.log(cursor.value.code);
                    cursor.continue();
                }
                else {
                    //cursor end
                    def.resolve(codes);
                }

            };
        };

        return def.promise;
    };
};
```

And the usage

```
//usage

$scope.getCodeFromDB("value")
.then(function(codes) {
    //codes filled
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This works fine. One question regarding the `usage`: Where should this code be written? In the service? And do I need the code?

Comment: if you need to use the getCodeFromDB in your code and do something with the loaded data you need to use it.

However if you call the function from the view, it's useless